# JBoss в развёрнутом EAR-приложении не подцепляет application.xml из проекта, а откуда-то берёт свой

Tags: jboss, java, java-ee

В файле application.xml в исходниках проекта прописан путь к web-контексту, по которому должно отзываться web-приложение:

```
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>myapp-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>MA</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

а в директории C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\myapp-ear.ear\META-INF
в файле application.xml - другое:

```
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>myapp-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/myapp-web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
```

И в итоге оно отзывается по адресу /myapp-web, а мне надо /MA
Откуда он берёт этот левый application.xml? Как его заставить брать правильный?

P.S.:
Раньше самого файла application.xml не было, он был добавлен позже. Но вычищение/обновление приложения не помогло, - JBoss не воспринимает application.xml.
А у другого коллеги воспринимает.

Comment: Собираете просто Maven'ом? В какой директории лежит `application.xml`? Что находится в файле `*.ear` в директории `target`?

Comment: Sorry за поздний ответ, были обстоятельства.

Собираю в Eclipse (Build automatically).
Файл application.xml лежит в директории \myapp\myapp-ear\src\main\application\META-INF
Файла .ear в директории target нет, но тут - спасибо за подсказку - нашлось: \myapp\myapp-ear\target\m2e-wtp\ear-resources\META-INF\application.xml
И там - тот устаревший автоматически созданный application.xml, который и использовался (вместо того, чтобы обновиться).

Comment: Здесь:  \myapp\myapp-ear\target\m2e-wtp\ear-resources\META-INF\application.xml
Я исправляю файл вручную, вставляю там правильный путь к web-модулю, а он всё равно заменяется на старый! Откуда он его берёт? Если НЕ из исходников (там всё нормально, путь правильный).

Answer (score 1):

Надо было в ...\myapp\myapp-ear\pom.xml раскомментировать и отредактировать:

```
       <modules>
          <webModule>
             <groupId>com.myapp.pkg</groupId>
             <artifactId>myapp-web</artifactId>
             <contextRoot>/MA</contextRoot>
          </webModule>
       </modules>
```